# The calling thread can not access this object because a different thread owns it having error

Tags: c#, .net

I have messagebox in one .cs file and i want to clear textbox which is in another .cs file on ok button click.
I have used

```
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
      _upload._txtbxNotes.Text = "";
}));
```

for solving threading issue .But it doesnt help me .it still shows the same error.
Any help appreciated.

---

Update:

Hello,I also updated my code but it does not change textbox value .it remain as it is .I have one more thread on upload screen for  progresssbar.

Here is my code:FileUpload.cs

```
            if (String.Equals(objFileUploadResponse.responseCode, 102))
            {
                //  MessageBox.Show("File Uploaded Successfully");

                ipbup.ReportProgress(qpvsChunk);
                DialogResult dialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("File Uploaded", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    _upload.SetNotes(" ");                                                                               
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("File Uploaded Failed");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Upload.cs:

```
public void SetNotes(string note)
{
    _txtbxNotes.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        _txtbxNotes.Text = note;
    });
}
```

Comment: Please take a moment to learn how the formatting works here. Select blocks of code and use the `{}` button.

Comment: Where do you set the `SetNotes()` different than `" "` ?

Comment: I have used SetNotes() in Upload screen.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because you are running on another thread. When you call the `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` on another thread, it will create a new `Dispatcher`. But you don't want a new dispatcher, you want to use the `Dispatcher` who 'owns' the control/window.

To solve this, your controls/window has a `Dispatcher` property. *(it referes to the Dispatcher it was created on)*

You can try:

```
// use the Dispatcher from the _upload control.
_upload._txtbxNotes.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    _upload._txtbxNotes.Text = "";
}));
```

---

A 'better' aproach could be: Creating a method within your `_upload` class called *(for example)* `_upload.SetNotes(string note);` This way you keep logic separated. Today you want a `TextBox` tomorrow you might want a `Label`. This way only your upload window/control/class is inflicted.

```
// for example:  (pseudo)

_upload.SetNotes("");


class UploadWindow
{
    // ......

    public void SetNotes(string note)
    {
        _txtbxNotes.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            _txtbxNotes.Text = note;
        }));
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello,I have tried this solution but it shows error at Invoke(Action).Why this error comes?Any help appreciated.Thanks in advance.